# AnyLogic - assign number to agent and use it for calculations

Tags: variables, numbers, anylogic, agent

I need help programming a process in AnyLogic.

I want to assign a specific number to an Agent (50%=1,20%=2,30%=3). And later I want to use the number to add to a stock.
For example: if the Agent has the number 3 I want the stock (variable) to go down exaclly this amount.

I tried using a Parameter on the Agent, but I am only able to create a string and with that I can't calculate later…

I would be very happy if anyone knows a solution to the Problem! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution for your case:

1. set the parameter type to "int"
2. Assign the initial value according to your probabilities, as below. Note that for numbers 2 and 3, it is a relative probability, given that it was not drawing value 1

Each agent instance will draw a number between 1 and 3 now (50% 1, 20% 2 and 30% 3). Then, you can do your stock adjustments with that param

[image]

Comment: Check out Java conditional statements, btw.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer! The parameter is all set now. But when I try to use it, it's not working.. for example: I want to use a "select output" where I set the condition to: "Parameter < stock". But than it tells me: "Unable to create a static reference for the non-static Order.ID (thats the Parameter) field" Do you know what I could do About that?

Comment: yes, you are not writing correct Java code. Likely, your parameter is called "myParameter" but in your code you write "MyParameter < stock". Notice the capital letters. Always use code-complete (Ctrl+Space) to write code. Java is case-sensitive.

Comment: You were right. I forgot the "agent." :) Thank you so much!

Comment: pleasure. Please flag the answer as "helpful" so others can find it easily in the future. (the up-arrow next to it)